# Loading an Image and adjusting it's width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an Issue with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#pic').attr("src", "image.jpg");
            if ($('#pic').width() > 85)
                $('#pic').attr("width", "85px");
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <img id="pic" src="">
    </body>
</html>
```

When opening the browser and surfing to that page the first time it loads it loads the "image.jpg" image with it's original width. after refreshing the width is 85px.

when alerting the width of the image after source has been set for the first time the width is 0px.

Please help, 
Thanks

Comment: You should listen to the `load` event. What's wrong with using CSS `max-width` property in your stylesheet?

Comment: `#pic{ max-width:85px; }`

Comment: Thanks undefined, this solves is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wait for the image to load before you can reference its attributes, etc

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7wuVb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pic').load(function() { 
        if ($('#pic').width() > 85)
                $('#pic').attr("width", "85px");
    });
    $('#pic').attr("src", "https://www.google.com/logos/2014/worldcup14/closing/cta.png");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set a css rule like,

```
#pic{
    width:85px;
}
```

?

Comment: This should occur only when picture width is larger then 85px; not setting static width for smaller images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using two separate style classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wuVb/1/

```
.outter 
{
  width: auto;
  max-width: 85px;
  max-height: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;    
}

.inner {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

<div class="outter">
    <img class="inner" id="pic" src="" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pic').attr("src", "https://www.google.com/logos/2014/worldcup14/closing/cta.png");
});
```

Avoid size manipulations in javascript as much as possible. Rely on CSS to do the job.